# Use system memory as GWT SuperDev mode working directory

Tags: gwt, working-directory, gwt-super-dev-mode, gwt-compiler

I'm using GWT SuperDev mode to compile a huge GWT project which produces a lot of codeserver temporary files. This files are stored in windows `%TEMP%` path and waste a lot of disk space and I have to clean them manually every day. In addition, accessing data on hard drive is definitely much slower than RAM, so I want to know is there any way to force GWT compiler to keep these files in the RAM instead of HDD when I'm debugging the project and free up memory after stopping SuperDev debug mode? (In other word I want to use system memory instead as working directory of GWT)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround was really simple: using a RAM Disk software such as [this one](https://www.softperfect.com/products/ramdisk/) to create a RAM disk drive and setting GWT working directory (using `-workDir` flag) to that drive.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to load this into memory. This has been an on going issue with gwt. Take a look at this bug report:

[Temp files issue](https://code.google.com/archive/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/5261)

If you read the comments there are some pretty good work arounds. They are not fixes for the issue, but they sure do improve upon the disk clean approach my team currently has to do.